# android - Wifi Direct Group Owner intent not functioning

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect two device to each other by wifi direct. I set the group owner intent to 15, like this :

```
config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;
```

but it does not work at all. Also I try to remove all of previous groups that are saved in devices in case of having impact on GO selection.
All the time the other device is getting to be GO. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you would want other device to be Group owner, then use the CreateGroup function to make a group on that device.

Comment: could you please describe about how the whole procedure should go?
 because in connect() function you will connect to other device by its address which has been obtained by peer discovery procedure. But I assume in your approach the client should ask for connection. If you could explain a little bit more or give me some references, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Basically everything would work exactly the same. Except that the GO would create the group before adding local services to advertise. The connection from client side is no different than with normal ways on working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;` works with same brands (for example, if both your devices are Samsungs). With different devices sometimes this bug appears.
Also it depends on your connection:

```
 manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

or

```
manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // Device is ready to accept incoming connections from peers.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "P2P group creation failed. Retry.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Your code doesn't help if you use the second one.

Having same problem with Samsung and Xiaomi now, always same group owner. If a test on both Samsungs everything is okay.